# What are the most efficient algorithms to recommend items to groups of users?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

Using collaborative filtering usually applies to giving ratings to an individual user, but how would these algorithms change when needing to recommend an item(s) to multiple people (for example: friends wanting to watch a movie or wanting to choose a holiday together)?

Comment: Read Toby Segaran's *Programming Collective Intelligence* http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is at a very general level, I will answer it at that level.

The key change is that a loss function that is typically minimized (or an objective function is maximized) for an individual would be minimized for a set.  Unless you have training data for sets, this tends to be very difficult.  What's more, the set could change depending on the recommendation.

Nonetheless, a naive approach would be to suggest a least common denominator item: one that, on average, maximizes the objective function.